# ¿Cómo salir/terminar un trigger?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tengo este trigger en mi tabla

```
Begin
    DECLARE VeCodTramite INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    /* Actualiza los días libres del almacenaje dependiendo de la condición que se ponga*/
    /* Los almacenajes solo se guardan los folios de entrada    ( eCodTabla = 1 )*/
    IF(NEW.iPkCondicionComercial != OLD.iPkCondicionComercial and OLD.eCodTabla = 1) THEN
        SELECT eCodTramite INTO VeCodTramite FROM pro_solicitudesentradas WHERE eCodSolicitud = OLD.eCodSolicitud;

        /*Si el trámite es Foráneo o Fiscal salimos de la función porque en esos no aplican los días libres*/
        IF (VeCodTramite IN (1)) THEN
            RETURN FALSE;
        END IF;

    END IF;
END
```

y quiero que cuando `VeCodTramite = 1`, se termine la ejecución del trigger, intente con `return` pero me sale el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe que sentencia es la que debo de usar?

Comment: ¿La condición por la que deseas salir, es una situación contemplada o un error que debería invalidar la ejecución del trigger?

Comment: Situación contemplada la cual invalida la ejecución del trigger ( todavia hay mas codigo abajo pero no lo puse )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tenes que usar la instruccion [Leave](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/leave.html), junto con un [label](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/statement-labels.html) creado a nivel del trigger de la siguiente forma

```
my_proc: Begin
    DECLARE VeCodTramite INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    /* Actualiza los dias libres del almacenaje dependiendo de la condicion que se ponga*/
    /* Los almacenjes solo se guardan los folios de entrada ( eCodTabla = 1 )*/
    IF(NEW.iPkCondicionComercial != OLD.iPkCondicionComercial and OLD.eCodTabla = 1) THEN
        SELECT eCodTramite INTO VeCodTramite FROM pro_solicitudesentradas WHERE eCodSolicitud = OLD.eCodSolicitud;

        /*Si el tramite es Foraneo o Fiscal salimos de la funcion porque en esos no aplican los dias libres*/
        IF (VeCodTramite IN (1)) THEN
            LEAVE my_proc;
        END IF;

    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Es que es un trigger, pongo el nombre del trigger?

Comment: en el begin del trigger pone el label...

Comment: ok, entonces no existe algo como exit?

Comment: si, leave.. eso hace el exit... te pase la documentacion...

Comment: ok, muchas gracias